# VSCode Integrated Terminal With no Word Wrap Still Inserts Line Breaks (but with no Carriage Return)

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, vscode-tasks

I would like to turn off word wrap in my vscode terminal so I can more easily view compiler messages.

e.g.

```
Imagine this is a very long line generated from a compiler and it has a lot of information and when it word wraps it is very hard to read so I would like vs code to just have a scroll bar at the bottom like SO has here.
```

However, after attempting several different methods of disabling word wrap, what is actually generated looks like:

```
Imagine this is a very long line generated from a compiler and it 
                                                                t has a lot of information and when it word wraps it is very hard to read so I would like vs code to just have a scroll bar at the bottom like SO has here.
```

(extra `t` on the second line is intentional)

So it appears that I've managed to turn off word wrap internal to vscode, but something is still causing a carriage return (with no line feed), I think?

These messages are produced by running a C++ build task in the integrated terminal that in turn calls cmd.exe to run a script (e.g. `cmd.exe <build command script>`

**Here is what I've tried so far:**

1. First thing I tried was turning off word wrap in vscode (alt + z, or View > Word Wrap). This led to the weird line break described above.
2. I was suspicious that cmd was the one causing this weird line break, so I disabled "wrap text output on resize" and set the screen buffer width manually to 1000 (1000 >> greater than any of my output lines) within
   [command prompt properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FvnGv.png) for both ["properties" and "default"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HaaB1.png). I then tested the same command running in my vscode terminal and it worked as expected in the cmd terminal but still not vscode.
3. I was suspicious powershell (which I think vs code uses in it's integrated terminal?) was the one causing the line break, so I set the properties the same as in the cmd image above. Again this worked as expected in the powershell terminal, but still not vscode.
4. Following this, I changed the ["terminal fixed dimensions"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJV7B.png) using the command from the command pallet and set the width to a [matching column width of 1000](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OR0jK.png) (leaving row empty for "automatic").
5. I've tried restarting vscode and my pc between several of these steps with no change.

What could be causing this behavior inside of the vscode terminal?

**Update:**

I have found the following to be a temporary work around. I was keyed into this from a comment in 2019 from Tyriar on [vscode GitHub Issue #81328](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/81328).

> The workaround is to open the terminal one time before running your task.
>
> On Windows wrapping is "owned" by the backend conpty and will sometimes reflow the page, whereas on Linux and macOS it's owned by VS Code. You should direct your comments to microsoft/terminal#405 as I would love this to get fixed as well.

The following steps somewhat fix my issue:

1. In the VS Code Terminal window, [open a powershell terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLR3S.png)
2. While the powershell terminal is open, run your build task (Terminal > Run Task...)
3. Follow step 1 from above.
4. Select the powershell terminal tab, then run the build task again.

The down side to this approach is that each subsequent run of the build task, you will need to select the powershell terminal before clicking Terminal > Run Task... In addition, you need to disable word wrap and column width each time you restart vs code.

This is still not ideal, but it at least gives me the behavior I want. From the GitHub issue #405 referenced, it sounds like this should be fixed but I'm not seeing that. Why would I be seeing this behavior?

Comment: What shell are you using? A terminal is not a shell. CMD is not PowerShell. Check what shell you are using in your VS Code's integrated terminal instance. For UNIX shells, see [How to disable line wrap in a terminal?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/20493/550426) (see the `tput` answer)

Comment: Possibly related GitHub issue: [Text Wrapping with ConPTY #405](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/405)

Comment: @user To your first comment--I am on a windows machine. So VS Code will use powershell as I alluded to above. I don't think UNIX shell commands won't apply here.

I think the GitHub issue you linked gets closest to what I'm looking for, but it is on the windows terminal repo, not vscode. I'm trying to search around some more for a vscode specific issue, but I can't tell if this issue has been identified/fixed except for the comment by Tyriar on #405.

Comment: @user I've seen this GitHub issue: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/91898 which is a vs code issue related to #405 you linked, but it appears to be merged and I'm on the latest vs code version. If that were the case, I can't figure why the fix wouldn't be active for me?